# 2x2 on exterior wall

Tags: framing

I am working on a kitchen remodel and pulled the plaster off of the exterior wall to find 2x2 studs with no insulation butting up to brick. My question is, do I have to reframe to meet code in the US?

I just had a bathroom remodel done, but can’t remember if there were 2x4s or 2x2s on the exterior wall. I know the contractor insulated the space, but don’t recall if he reframed the wall.